# How to speeden up schema agreement in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, cqlsh

I have a 3 node 2.x Cassandra cluster with an out of the box configuration. My java program uses the datastax driver (2.19) to create the schema by executing CQL/DDL statements one at a time. What I am finding is that many times schema changes take tens of seconds for schema agreement for several statements. The statement which takes a long time is pretty much random.

I am looking for tips on how to improve the speed of schema agreement.

Note :- when I create the schema using cqlsh it's pretty fast.

UPDATE 08/12/2016

I added the following code to execute a statement and then wait for schema agreement so that I could get a little more insight into how long the wait is.

```java
private void executeStatement(String statement, PrintStream out) throws DBInstallerException {
    int retries = 0;
    final ResultSet resultSet = session.execute(statement);

    if (!resultSet.getExecutionInfo().isSchemaInAgreement()) {
        for (; retries < TOTAL_WAIT_FOR_SCHEMA_AGREEMENT_IN_SECONDS; retries++) {
            Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (cluster.getMetadata().checkSchemaAgreement()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (retries >= TOTAL_WAIT_FOR_SCHEMA_AGREEMENT_IN_SECONDS) {
        throw new DBInstallerException("Failed to get schema agreement after " + TOTAL_WAIT_FOR_SCHEMA_AGREEMENT_IN_SECONDS + " seconds");
    } else {
        if (retries > 0 ) {
            out.println("INFO : Got schema agreement after " + retries + " retries");
        }
    }
}
```

Many times I get the "Got schema agreement after " output printed to console and the retries can be as many as 300. This is what does not make sense to me. How could any schema change take that long to execute on a system which is essentially idle.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a direct answer to your question, but it may be contributing to things being slower using the datastax driver vs. cqlsh.  There was an inefficiency in the driver where it was debouncing schema refreshes when a client made a schema change when it shouldn't have ([JAVA-1120](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1120)) delaying the return time from executing each  schema-related statement by 1 second.

If you are able to, upgrading to java-driver 3.0.3+ will fix this for you.

Otherwise you can disable schema refresh debouncing like this:

```java
Cluster.builder()
  .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setRefreshSchemaIntervalMillis(0))
  //... more builder options
  .build()
```

Comment: I tried both these options and I am not seeing a speed-up. Note that I am seeing schema agreement sometimes take minutes after a DDL is executed. There is not a lot of data read write going on at the time I modify the schema. Avg wait time of the disk is also pretty low so I'm not getting what could be taking such a long time. It seems like it should be a driver issue but I'm not able to pinpoint what.